# How to Display image on specified URL using PHP

Tags: php, image, show

I want to display different images at a specified URL's using php.
So if page name is `www.website.com/?file=page_1` then show `image_1.png` within the main page.

I can't find out how to do so in php code or don't know where to look for.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are very beginner in PHP. What you are trying to do is called HTTP GET Parameters. And are you sure it is `?file=page_1` and not `?file=image_1`?

To get it, you need to do this:

```
<img src="image_<?php echo (strpos("page_", $_GET["file"] === 0)) ? str_replace("page_", "", $_GET["file"]) : ""; ?>.png" alt="Image" />
```

If it is a mistake of yours, and it is `?file=image_1`, then you can simply use this code:

```
<img src="<?php echo (strpos("image_", $_GET["file"] === 0)) ? $_GET["file"] : ""; ?>.png" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one. I'm a beginner indeed.. But i can reed your code. I used your code as above but this did not had the right result. ig the image was not displayed. It seems the link is broken? The Page URL is displayed as ?files=pagename

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = array(1 => "image1.jpg", 2 => "image2.jpg");

if (isset($images[$_GET["page"]])){
    print $images[$_GET["page"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to get remote content displayed on your site. There is a small **risk** in doing this, if the website is down, your website also suffers.

```
$GLOBALS['images'] = array();

// Fetch the page content
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
$pageContent = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


function splitByRegex($match)
{
  $GLOBALS['images'] = $match[1];
}

// Strip the images from the content
preg_replace_callback(
    '/\<img.*src\=\"(.*\.(?:png)|(?:jpg)|(?:gif))\"\>/ig',
    'splitByRegex'
    $pageContent
);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($GLOBALS['images'], true) . '</pre>';
```

On that note, I think you should read up on the following:

- [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to fetch the content of the page
- Regular Expressions for interpreting the content:

  - [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) functions for interpreting the fetched content
  - [Regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to tell the PRCE functions what to look for